# I am trying to make 2 filters work together. I want the already selected option's value to go on getdata1.php page without selecting the category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please help I am stuck in this for a long time.
I have given all the necessary code. 
There are three parts in it .
I am trying to make 2 filters work together. I want the already selected option's value to go on getdata1.php page without selecting the category.
Here is the script for filtering category.

```
<script>

function showUser(str) {

      if (str=="" ) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Here is the Code for range slider from price

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
     // Initializing slider
     $( "#slider" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500000,
        values: [ 0, 500000 ],
        step:1000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            // Get values
            var min = ui.values[0];
            var max = ui.values[1];
            $('#range').text(min+' - ' + max);
            // AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData1.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {min:min,max:max},
                success: function(response){
                       // Updating table data
                       $('#emp_table tr').remove();
                       $('#emp_table').append(response); 
                } 
            });
         }
     });   
});

</script>
```

Here is the html part

```
<div id="slider"></div><br/>
Range: <span id='range'></span>
<form><p class="filter_heading"><b>Category</b>
</p>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="nul" selected ></option>
          <option value="aa">aa</option>
          <option value="bb">bb</option>
          <option value="cc">cc</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Here is my getdata1.php

```
<?php

$q = strval($_GET['q']); 
include 'connection.php';

/* Range */
echo "$q";
$min = $_POST['min'];
$max = $_POST['max'];

/* Query */
if (strpos($q,'nul') !== false)
{
    $query=mysqli_query($con," SELECT * FROM adv_fb_price_photo WHERE 
    photo_min>=$min AND photo_max<=$max"); 
    $html = '';
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {  
      $brand=$row['brand'];
      $category=$row['category'];
      $photo_min=$row['photo_min'];
      $photo_max=$row['photo_max'];
      $html .='<tr>';
      $html .='<td>'.'Brand: '.$brand.'<br>Category: '.$category.'<br>

        Minimum price:

        '.$photo_min.'<br>Maximum price: '.$photo_max.'</td>';
      $html .='</tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    $query1=mysqli_query($con," SELECT* FROM adv_fb_price_photo WHERE (photo_min>=$min AND photo_max<=$max) AND (category='$q')"); 
    $html = '';
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
    {  
      $brand=$row1['brand'];
      $category=$row1['category'];
      $photo_min=$row1['photo_min'];
      $photo_max=$row1['photo_max'];
      $html .='<tr>';
      $html .='<td>'.'Brand: '.$brand.'<br>Category: '.$category.'<br>Minimum price: '.$photo_min.'<br>Maximum price: '.$photo_max.'</td>';
      $html .='</tr>';
    }
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: It is really difficult to understand with this information. Can you actually explain well on what is the problem at the moment and what you need

Comment: Sir if I am filtering first according to the price ,then it is working but if I want that data to be filtered according to category an error is coming q index unidentified. Therfore I decided to keep value already selected in the category part but it is still not working.